# Get single posts archive information

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I noticed something when I var_dump(); on a single page in wordpress. Its not linked to its archive page at all or any parents. Is it at all possible to get the single pages archive information as if it were a parent page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the archive link of a post type use [`get_post_type_archive_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_type_archive_link/):

```
print get_post_type_archive_link( get_post_type( $GLOBALS['post']->ID ) );
```